# Why does printing out local data mess with MPI_GATHERV results?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

The following code needs 12 processors to run properly.

```
program GameOfLife
use mpi
implicit none
integer ierr, myid, numprocs
integer send, recv, count, tag
parameter (tag=111)
integer recv_buff, send_buff, request
integer stat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
integer N, m, i, j, sum
parameter (N=3) !# of squares per a processors
integer W, H
parameter (W=4,H=3) !# of processors up and across
integer A(N,N), buff(0:N+1,0:N+1), G(N*H, N*W)
! real r
integer sizes(2), subsizes(2), starts(2), recvcount(N*N)
integer newtype, intsize, resizedtype
integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) extent, begin
integer disp(W*H)

call MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr)

! fill up subgrid 
do i = 1, N
     do j = 1, N
        ! call random_number(r)
        A(i,j) = myid! floor(r*2)
     end do
end do

do i = 1, N
    print *, A(i, :)
end do

starts   = [0,0]
sizes    = [N*H, N*W]
subsizes = [N, N]

call MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, sizes, subsizes, starts, &
                            MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INTEGER, newtype, ierr)
call MPI_Type_size(MPI_INTEGER, intsize, ierr)
extent = intsize*N
begin  = 0
call MPI_Type_create_resized(newtype, begin, extent, resizedtype, ierr)
call MPI_Type_commit(resizedtype, ierr)

disp = [0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20, 27, 28, 29]

recvcount = 1

call MPI_GATHERV(A,N*N,MPI_INTEGER,G,recvcount,disp,resizedtype,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
call MPI_WAIT(request, stat, ierr)

if ( myid == 0 ) then
    do i = 1, N*H
        print *, G(i,:)
    end do
endif

call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

end program GameOfLife
```

When ran without printing out the matrix A, everything works mostly okay. But If I try to print out A before feeding it to the gather statement, I get a jumbled mess.

What's going on here? I assume memory is trying to be accessed at the same time or something along those lines.

Output of G looks like

```
       0           0           0           4           4           4           0 -1302241474           1          13          13          13
       0           0           0           4           4           4           0           0           0          13          13          13
       0           0           0           4           4           4   -10349344   -12542198   -10350200          13          13          13
       1           1           1           5           5           5          59          59          59          14          14          14
       1           1           1           5           5           5 -1342953792           0           0          14          14          14
       1           1           1           5           5           5       32767           0           0          14          14          14
       2           2           2           6           6           6 -1342953752  1451441280           0          15          15          15
       2           2           2           6           6           6       32767       10985           0          15          15          15
       2           2           2           6           6           6   -10350200           1           0          15          15          15
       3           3           3           7           7           8           8           8          12          12          12           0
       3           3           3           7           7           8           8           8          12          12          12           0
       3           3           3           7           7           8           8           8          12          12          12           0
```

Comment: there is no global ordering when printing to standard output, so you should not expect `A` to be printed in order. Instead, you should either gather the matrix on a node and print it from there, or have each process print its part to a file with MPI-IO

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet No, it messes up G. The gathered matrix comes out all scrambled

Comment: It's just that accessing A right before gathering messes up the gather. Doesn't seem like that should happen

Comment: how do you know which output is for `A` and which is for `G`?

Comment: there is no issue on my side. fwiw, my compiler does not accept this program since the receive counts is a scalar instead of an array.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet well A is much smaller

Comment: I suggest you write the outputs from different processes to different files to make it clear what corresponds to what. But as @GillesGouaillardet says this program is broken - the recvcount argument to mpi_gatherv must be an array.

Comment: Voting to close: if the recvcounts bug is fixed the code compiles and runs correctly with gfortran -fcheck=all

Comment: @IanBush fixed the bug and this in fact does not fix the issue

Comment: The ordering of printing is not guaranteed. The processes run totally asynchronously. MPI_Barrier is not enough to synchornise the I/O. A jumbled mess is the expected behaviour. If you want ordered I/O you *must* use separate files or MPI I/O or something built on it (e.g. netcdf, HDF5).

Comment: @IanBush I omitted the outputs of A. They look fine. It's G that is a mess.

Comment: The recvcount array in the above code is only 9 elements long. If I correct it to 12 elements as required for running on 12 processes and delete the unneeded MPI wait (which introduces an uninitialized variable bug) the code works for me.

Comment: @IanBush This did indeed solve my errors. Thank you. I'm curious what the uninitialized variable bug is though.

Comment: Request is not initialized when you make the unnecessary call to MPI_wait, and it is an Intent( InOut) argument